# conditionally use a middleware depending on request parameter express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to decide on a middleware to use based on request query parameter.

in the main module I have something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res){
  if (req.query.something) {
    // pass req, res to middleware_a
  } else {
    // pass req, res to middleware_b
  }
});
```

`middleware_a` and `middleware_b` are **both express apps** themselves created by `express()` function and not regular middleware functions (`function(req, res, next)`)

can't find a way to do it

Comment: what's wrong with your code? as an express maintainer, this is how i would suggest you do this.

Comment: @JonathanOng the problem is that `middleware_a` and `middleware_b` are both objects created by `express()` and not regular middleware functions, so I can't really pass req, res, next to them...

Comment: express apps are themselves middleware. yes you can.

Comment: @JonathanOng How ? can you demonstrate ? It tells me that the object is not a function when I try to do something like `middleware_a(req, res, next)`

Comment: sounds like you're doing something wrong. can you post a complete example

Answer (score 50):

There is nothing magical about connect/express 'middleware': they are just functions - and you can call them as you would call any other function.

So in your example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.query.something) {
    middlewareA(req, res, next);
  } else {
    middlewareB(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

That said, there might be more elegant ways of constructing hierarchical express applications. Check out [TJ's video](http://vimeo.com/56166857)

Comment: thats the thing. My app is built same like on TJ's video. So middleware_a and middleware_b are actually objects and not functions, so I can't really pass a `req, res, next` to them. Express knows to differentiate between these two and handle both of them when passing either one of them to a middleware

Answer (score 11):

I know this issue is old, but I would like to share my solution. I solved this by making a function that returned a Middleware with a callback.

Example middleware:

```
function isAdminUser(callback){
    return function(req, res, next){
        var userId = callback(req);
        // do something with the userID
        next();
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following in the express router object

```
app.use(isAdminUser(function(req){
    return req.body.userId
    });
```

Comment: This is an elegant way, I think use it if I don't found an even better way

Comment: It should be `req` not `res` i.e. `function(req){
    return req.body.userId
    }`

Answer (score 6):

I would not use that middleware - instead in middleware A and B check for whatever:

```
//Middleware A
app.use(function(req, res){

  // If it doesn't match our condition then send to next middleware
  if (!req.query.something) {
    next();
  } else {
    // We're good - let this middleware do it's thing
    ...
    next();
   }
});
```

Same with middleware B

```
//Middleware B
app.use(function(req, res){

  if (req.query.something) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you landed here looking to use a 3rd party middleware under a conditional middleware (such as passport or sessions) like I did, this is how you do it:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // your condition
    if (req.url !== 'no-session') {
      // Your middleware
      session()(req, res, next);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  })
```

This will only trigger the session when the condition is met. You have to send (req, res, next) as the arguments to the second function which it's always returned to connect middlewares. This should work for any middleware, be it your own or 3rd party.

Comment: This is spot on! I wanted to conditionally do the 
`passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })` 
after this answer what I did was
`return passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(req, res, next)`

Answer (score 2):

I know I am a bit late for this thread but you can use this plugin 
[Express Conditional Tree Middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-conditional-tree-middleware).

It allows you to combine multiple and async middleware. 
Specifically, you can create two classes that represent your middleware (middleware_a, middleware_b) and inside the `applyMiddleware` methods that will reside in those classes return a promise that is created by your middleware function or a custom resolved promise with your result from your middleware function again.

Then in your main js file, you can create a chainer depending on your needs to combine those middlewares conditionally! Check out the docs for more information, it will get more clear after checking the code.

Comment: now it looks like a proper answer. I retraced my flag and deleted my (now irrelevant) comments.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for letting me know again, i am pretty new here :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need, so I created a wrapper to create conditional middleware.

```js
const conditionalMiddleWare = function(condition) {
  return function(middleware) {
    return function(req, res, next) => {
      if (
        (typeof condition == 'boolean' && condition) ||
        (typeof condition == 'function' && condition(req, res, next))
      ) {
        return middleware(req, res, next);
      }
      next();
    };
  }
}
```

You can use it with a boolean value

```js
// Only use this middleware on production environment
forProduction = conditionalMiddleWare(server.settings.env === 'production');
server.use(forProduction(auth.connect()));
```

You can decide on the fly with a function, according to the request

```js
// Only use this middleware when it's not the `/api/` folder that is requested
const forNotApi = conditionalMiddleWare(function(req) {
 return !req.path.startsWith('/api/');
});
server.use(forNotApi(express.static(rootDir)));
```

I hope it could help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you probably missing the trick. 
Each piece of middleware is a request handler. You start by looking at the first request handler, then you look at the next one, then the next, and so on.

Here's what middleware basically looks like:

```
function myFunMiddleware(request, response, next) {
// Do stuff with the request and response.
// When we're all done, call next() to defer to the next middleware.
next();
}
```

I would suggest you to amend your code to something like this.

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  if (request.url == "/") {
  response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  response.end(".. Any custom msg..\n");
 // The middleware stops here.
  } 
  else {
  next();
}});
```

Please to through this [tutorial](http://stephensugden.com/middleware_guide/), i am sure you will get a good overview of using middlewares. Have a happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For async functions, you could do something like this:

```js
// Generic middleware style function.
const processData = async(data) => {
  // Do some processing.
  const processedData = await something(data);
  if (response.error) {
    return [{message: "There was an error"}];
  }
  return [ false, processedData ]
}


const routeMiddleware = async(req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.data.property === 'a') {
    const [ err, processedData] = await processData(req.body.data);
    if (err) next(err);
    return res.json({ message: 'Successfully processed', processedData});
  } else {
    return res.json({ message: 'Not processed'});
  }
}
```

Advantages of this pattern:

- The processData() function can be reused elsewhere in the app
- Easily readable
- Uses async/await

Wrapping a try/catch block around the async function call is also probably a good idea, or use @awaitjs/express.